# How to properly use VirtualHost and mod_proxy together for different incoming domain names and internal ports?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I am trying to setup httpd.conf properly but regardless of the sub-domain/domain combo below, they all resolve to the same internal URL.

```
<Proxy *>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests       Off


<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername      jira.firstfactoryinc.com
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass       /   http://localhost:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8082/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername      jira.submitpatientforms.com
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass       /   http://localhost:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername      mddev-jira.firstfactoryinc.com
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass       /   http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a `NameVirtualHost` directive that matches your `<VirtualHost>` definitions, or else the first `<VirtualHost>` block to load will be used for all requests on that port (this matches with what you're seeing, correct?).

In the case of the config above:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Outside of a `VirtualHost` block.  Alongside your `Listen` directive is a good place for it.

Comment: I just realized this and came back to post this as a solution.

Comment: Was about to say the same... in addition, you may find http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy to be a useful example.  I essentially emulated that when I was tasked with a similar setup a few years back

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add something like this within each VirtualHost, I did:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Obviously that can be modified to suit your security needs.

You may also want to add:

```
ProxyRequests Off
```

It is supposed to be the default, but depending on your Apache version and mod_proxy version something could be acting up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't make a difference. They are all still going to the first one.

Comment: Just for kicks have you tried specifying the listening port in the virtual host just to see if it makes a difference?
<VirtualHost *:80> --or whatever port you have
    Servername      jira.domain-two.com
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass       /   http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Also, you may want to add all of your domain names to your /etc/hosts file with the IP address they resolve to - I have seen that problem before as well... - not necessarily the subdomains - but the root domains at least.

Comment: I tried your second suggestion and still no luck. Regarding the IPs, they are all the same (one IP) and resolving correctly.

Comment: Which Apache and mod_proxy versions do you have and is this on Linux/Mac/Windows/etc..?

Comment: Also, another thing that comes to mind is why the localhost? Why not..

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername      jira.submitpatientforms.com
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyPass       /   http://jira.submitpatientforms.com:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://jira.submitpatientforms.com:8081/
</VirtualHost>